# Binding OSMDroid library in a MonoDroid 4.1 Java binding project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I just installed [MonoDroid](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/02/01/introducing-monodroid-intro.aspx/) alpha 4.1, and I'm trying to create a binding library project using the OSMDroid JAR file. [OSMDroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) is an opensource mapview implementation, basically a replacement for the [Google Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps) mapview. I followed the steps in the [tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Binding_a_Java_Library_%28.jar%29), but I get only an error message saying

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Novell\Xamarin.Android.Bindings.targets(170,5): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Since this is an alpha release that was just released yesterday I would suggest taking this to the mailing list or filing a bug report instead of raising the question here.

Comment: I realized this just after posting the question here. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4288.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to compile the project adding the following JAR files to the project.

- apache-mime4j-0.4.jar
- httpmime-4.0-beta1.jar
- osmdroid-third-party-3.0.7.jar
- slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar

and setting them as "ReferenceJar" in the properties in the build action.

To see a proper output from Visual Studio, in order to debug this issue, I also had to set the build output details to normal in Visual Studio options (tools-options-projects and solutions-build and run and set [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) project build output to normal).

I still have no luck in using the library, but at least it compiles!